# if-conditional tracing a half-sphere

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, conditional

I have a 2D discrete plane `(x,y)` and I would like to assign an amplitude to each point in the plane. Each dimension runs from -1 to 1.

Say I want to assign an `amplitude` of 1 around the origin and 0 everywhere else. Then I use the conditional `If[-0.1 < x < 0.1 && 0.1 > y > -0.1, amplitude = 1, amplitude = 0]`, which takes the form of a cube when we visualize it.

However, what conditional do I use when I want to the function to have a semi-spherical shape of radius 1? I.e., the amplitude should take the shape of a semi-spherical cap.

Comment: Ponder on $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

Comment: @J.M.isback. Thanks, that was also my initial thought. When I try it out, then I get the value 1/sqrt(2) for all x and y at the edge where x=+/-y=0.5, whereas I believe it should have the value 0

Comment: Well, you asked for a radius of $1$, you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mydata = Table[
   If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], 0], 
     {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}];
ListPlot3D[mydata, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     Filling -> Bottom,
     Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

If you want a smooth "cap," then delete `InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> None`.

One way to get the axes labels proper:

```
   mydata = Table[{x, y, If[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2], 0]},
       {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}];
   ListPlot3D[Flatten[mydata, 1],
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   Filling -> Bottom,
   Mesh -> None]
```

[image]